# How to pass multiple username in JIRA REST API to get bulk users?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am referring to below mention Rest API, It returns details of users specified in a list of usernames or key, It's mention in doc to provide Comma-separated list of usernames.

[Get Bulk User Jira API](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/?utm_source=%2Fcloud%2Fjira%2Fplatform%2Frest%2F&utm_medium=302#api-api-2-user-bulk-get)

This API is working perfectly when pass single username, but when I pass multiple emails (Comma separated it doesn't work)

```
curl -D- \
   -X GET \
   -H "Authorization: Basic Secret_Key" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   "https://mydomain.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user/bulk?username=**myusername**"
```

Above curl command works perfectly fine, but I am not able to search multiple username in single query, if I pass comma separated usernames it returns empty result.

Answer (score 0):

the document said "To specify multiple users, pass multiple username parameters". So you will need to repeat the parameter, like `/user/bulk?username=**myusername**&username=**anothername**`